# Disabling .ccexclude Files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clearcase

We are developing on Visual Studio 2008 with Clearcase integration. Some of our project files have rules which include all files (`**`) within a particular directory. Sometimes this results in Clearcase creating `.ccexclude` files. The [IBM documentation on `.ccexclude` files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21129630), says that there is a way to disable the creation of these files, but doesn't document how.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- to exclude the automatic adding of *.ccexclude files (created by ClearCase VisualStudio Add-on during excluding or including files into the project) into CC, please set up Exclude File Types in your Visual Studio Environment:

[Tools]->[Options...]->[Rational ClearCase]->[File Types]

and put there "*.ccexclude" into text box. Press OK. Afterwards you have to restart your Visual Studio Environment.

Answer (score 0):

> `.CCEXCLUDE` (ClearCase Exclusion File)
>
> When using the ClearCase and VS .NET Integration, a file called `.ccexclude` will be created if you choose the option "Exclude from Project" for a particular project file from within the Solution Explorer window.
> This file is simply a reference file that ClearCase uses to identify what files should not be included with specific source controlling operations, builds, etc.
> **This option can be enabled and disabled at the preference of the developer(s).**

The last part means there should be a Visual Studio ClearCase plugin preference (i.e. a preference within Visual Studio) allowing you to specify if you want a `.CCEXCLUDE` file to be created/updated each time you exclude a file from a (Visual Studio) project.

Note: that `.CCEXCLUDE` file is not a file known by ClearCase, but only by the Visual Studio ClearCase integration plugin, in order to not propose any checkout or "add to source control" operation for certain files excluded from the project.

Comment: Yes, I read that. I couldn't find the preference and hence the question on SO.

Comment: @Rohit: do you have a problem similar to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=280783&tstart=120 ?

Comment: Yes that's the exact issue being faced. Unfortunately, I don't see any useful answer to the poster's question in the forum post.

Comment: @Rohit: I thought so, but that look more like a bug than a setting issue. Any .keep file should not be automatically added to the `.CCEXCLUDE` file.